# Requesting customer service account notes

Tags: united-states, business, wisconsin

In another question, [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/9694/business-not-honoring-promotional-credits-despite-extensive-efforts-to-work-with), I had called into my phone company's customer service number in regards to trying to resolve an issue. Part of that back-and-forth discussion ended with me requesting the account notes they had for me on file. I was told by the representative, who claimed to have 7 years of experience in customer service management, that it was *illegal* for them to give out *proprietary* account notes like those.

I was intrigued because about 2 months prior I was gathering information to write a formal letter to their correspondence team. In a single night, I made a similar request for account notes and was told they couldn't provide them. Within an hour, I got in touch again with the same request and the lady had provided me with what seemed to be a direct copy/paste of the account notes for more than half of the days that involved my issue. Sometimes you have to ask twice, I suppose.

**Question:**

- What would make providing those account notes *illegal* when it would seem like the company would be the one "owns" them?

My limited research seemed to suggest that it might involve the [Law of Proprietary Information](http://www.inc.com/encyclopedia/proprietary-information.html). However, wouldn't that require someone else (third party?) to be the actual owner of those notes, thus limiting the public availability.

Answer (score 1):

Customer service could have been contracted out to a third party with contractual obligations to the company you are ostensibly dealing with.